# How to decrypt a md5 value in php

Tags: php, md5

in bellow code firstly i converted

str='test';
str2=md5(str);

but now i want to decrypt   str2 to  actual value, i want 'test' value again . Please help me 
Thanx

  -

---

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is a hashing function, so it cannot be decrypted. The only way of doing it is by having a dictionary (a database of a lot of MD5 hashes) and looking for your hash.

Answer (score 0):

`md5` is a hashing function, not an encryption function. You can't decrypt a hash. You can brute force it, use dictionaries, or exploit a hashing vulnerability.

You cannot decrypt what is not encrypted.